# How to copy all content in a webpage using selenium in headless mode?

Tags: selenium

Below I describe the issue I need help with.

**Description**
I wan't to simple copy content from URL: https://www.di.se/bors/large-cap/ to my Windows clipboard. I scroll down a bit on webpage (to get all content) and mark all before copy.
I want to this in selenium headless mode.

**Problem**
When I scroll down a little on the page and mark all and then copy the content, the clipboard does not contain the content I copied in headless mode in selenium. Important to know that this working as expected in normal selenium mode.
I have tried with three different browsers: Chrome, Edge and with Firefox. I have also tried with different ways to make the nessecary key strokes (sendKey, Actions and with the Robot class). See code example of the different ways below. Regardles what I'm doing the content is never copied to the clipboard.

Examples:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("scroll(0,400)");


driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"));
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "c"));



Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    Action selectAll=builder.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("a").keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build();
    Action copy=builder.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("c").keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build();
    selectAll.perform();
    copy.perform();


iRobot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    iRobot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A); 
    iRobot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
    iRobot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    iRobot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    iRobot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C); 
    iRobot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_C);
    iRobot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

**Question**
Is there a way to copy the content to clipboard or can some workaround help?

Comment: Do you specifically need to scroll, for example, to load content on the page, or can you just download the html as it is, which you can do without selenium at all?

Comment: I have a small screen (15.1") with 150% zoom therefor I must scroll to get content. Download the webpage is not the solution hence JavaScript content is not downloaded only HTML.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can find, it seems there is no way to access the clipboard in headless mode. I can't find anything definitive but this is as close as I can get to proof that it can't be done: https://groups.google.com/g/selenium-users/c/-nxTX4eTbwA/m/wQY_HlZQBAAJ